# Почему не работает vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Установил vuelidate: npm install vuelidate
main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './index.css'
import './assets/tailwind.css'
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(Vuelidate).mount('#app')
```

Пытаюсь в компоненте вывести переменную $v, но ничего не происходит. В консоли предупреждение:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "$v" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <Home onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Comment: import Vuelidate from "vuelidate"; так разве подключается? Смотрите документацию https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate

Comment: Переустановил, но всё равно не работает.